# C# and Visio 2013 - problems connecting two shapes

Tags: c#, .net, visio

I have Problems with C# (Visual Studio 2017) and Visio 2013. I am Writing a program to create organograms. It seems to work very well, but when i have different Masters for shapes, they are not connected.

My Main Problem:
The Tree is drawn just as I want - but when I use different Master-Shapes (for example: using masterShapes[1] instead of 0 at the line marked with many "#") The Connections of my whole tree are messed up. When I use equal shapes, it works.
I tried so many ways of drawing my tree, but it always does the same.

Just for the Information: TreeNode is a downloaded Tree that works very well. The Data from the treenode is from thge Class ChartData which can either be an Employee or an InformationItem. Both have to be drawn by visio in the same tree by Visio but they have to use different shapes. In my example, I am using the Default organization-chart-template that Comes with visio. I also always place the new shape at 0/0 because that was the safest way that it does not Auto connect with random shapes.

This is my method to draw the tree:

```
    //generates the diagram by using an existing tree
    public void GenerateDiagramFromTree(TreeNode<ChartData> pTree, string pTemplatePath, string pSavePath, bool pVisible = false)
    {
        //creating the visio-application
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application();
        application.Visible = pVisible;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Document doc = application.Documents.Add(pTemplatePath);

        //add the page for the diagram
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Page page = application.Documents[1].Pages[1];

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Master[] masterShapes;
        masterShapes = new Master[2];
        masterShapes[0] = doc.Masters.get_ItemU(@"Manager Belt");
        masterShapes[1] = doc.Masters.get_ItemU(@"Vacancy Belt");


        Shape shape = GetOrganogramShape(pTree.Data, doc, page, masterShapes);

        //draw each node of the tree
        drawTree(pTree, doc, page, shape, masterShapes);

        //finally: save the file
        page.Layout();
        string fileName = pSavePath + Guid.NewGuid() + ".vsdx";
        doc.SaveAs(fileName);
        doc.Close();


    //recursive call for drawing all employees
    public void drawTree(TreeNode<ChartData> pTree, Document pDoc, Page pPage, Shape pShape, Master[] pMasterShapes)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(pTree.Data.ToString() + " - Parent: " + ((Employee)pTree.Data).ReportingLine);
        //there should always be data!
        if (pTree.Children.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode<ChartData> currentChild in pTree.Children)
            {

                Shape childShape = GetOrganogramShape(currentChild.Data, pDoc, pPage, pMasterShapes);

                //connectWithDynamicGlueAndConnector(pShape, childShape);
                pShape.AutoConnect(childShape, VisAutoConnectDir.visAutoConnectDirNone);

                //recursive call for each child giving the shape that we created at the moment
                drawTree(currentChild, pDoc, pPage, childShape, pMasterShapes);

            }

        }
    }
```

And here is how I create the shapes

```
    private Shape GetOrganogramShape(ChartData pChartData, Document pDoc, Page pPage, Master[] pMasterShapes)
    {
        Shape returnShape;

        if(pChartData is Employee)
        {
            //get the shape
            returnShape = pPage.Drop(pMasterShapes[0], 0, 0);

            //set the cells
            Employee currentWorkingEmployee = (Employee)pChartData;
            returnShape.Cells["Prop.Name"].FormulaU = "\"" + currentWorkingEmployee.Surname + "\"";
        }
        else if(pChartData is InformationItem)
        {
            //get the shape
            //##############################################################
            returnShape = pPage.Drop(pMasterShapes[1], 0, 0);

            InformationItem currentWorkingInformationItem = (InformationItem)pChartData;

            returnShape.Cells["Prop.Name"].FormulaU = "\"" + currentWorkingInformationItem.ToString() + "\"";
        }
        //this case should never happen
        else
        {
            //get the shape
            throw new Exception("Shape to generate was not for an Employee or InformationItem");
        }

        //set the shape width
        returnShape.get_CellsSRC(
            (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisSectionIndices.
            visSectionObject,
            (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisRowIndices.
            visRowXFormIn,
            (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisCellIndices.
            visXFormWidth).ResultIU = 2.5;

        //set the shape height
        returnShape.get_CellsSRC(
           (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisSectionIndices.
           visSectionObject,
           (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisRowIndices.
           visRowXFormIn,
           (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisCellIndices.
           visXFormHeight).ResultIU = 1;

        System.Drawing.Color BackColor = new System.Drawing.Color();
        BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

        //set the shape fore color
        returnShape.Characters.set_CharProps(
            (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.
                VisCellIndices.visCharacterColor,
            (short)Utilities.GetVisioColor(Colors.Black));

        //set the shape back color
        returnShape.get_CellsSRC((short)VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject,
               (short)VisRowIndices.visRowFill, (short)VisCellIndices.visFillForegnd).FormulaU = "RGB(" + BackColor.R.ToString() + "," + BackColor.G.ToString() + "," + BackColor.B.ToString() + ")";
        return returnShape;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what "messed up" means. I suspect the shapes are still correctly connected, but the routing of the connector is not nice?

This is probably due to the setup of the masters and your code making an autoconnect, instead of connecting specific points of the shapes.

You may also want to check the routing settings of the drawing (rather a lot - to be found in the shapesheet of the document and of the page).